# Code under class does not output when run

Tags: python, class, oop

I am new at classes and OOP in general. When I run this code via terminal it does not display anything, as if I pressed Enter:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,health,damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Total damage = '+str(self.damage)+' and total health = '+str(self.health)

def main():
    newPlayer = Player(10000,3000)
    print(newPlayer)
```

I have also tried running it in IDLE , same result. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you call `main`?

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need this instead of main if you're executing the script standalone

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    newPlayer = Player(10000,3000)
    print(newPlayer)
```

Comment: You don't *need* that.